# How to import python file from parent folder?

Tags: python3

I tried to import python file from parent folder but keep getting error. How can i do it ? script is my python file. I am using jupyter notebook. All give error below.

```
from ... import script
from .. import script
from . import script
```

Comment: stackoverflow might be a more appropriate place for this question, but you can't use relative imports in a simple python script.  relative imports only work within  a python package.  you can have your file manipulate the import path so that python searches that additional directory, but it generally leads to buggy code.

Comment: so there is no proper way to do it ?

Comment: you can `import sys; sys.path.append('/path.to.parent.dir')` but it's messy and leads to poorly maintained code

Comment: thank you. i guess i have to figure out how to organize my folders then since i have multiple files in different folders importing script. This sucks

Comment: I want to further call out why it's bad to manipulate sys.path.  If you start leaving code in arbitrary places and you're using sys.path tricks for code reuse, you are writing code that nobody else can understand how it works without: 1 - having access to your filesystem and 2 - carefully inspecting the state of the import path at runtime.  If you want to do this correctly, move your code into a structure that makes it reusable or bundle it as a package if it's actually worth reusing (make a library)